# Calculating distance from latlang --MySQL functional error (#1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am creating a function for calculating the haversian distance but in i am getting the Mysql syntax error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION GEODIST (lat1 DOUBLE, lon1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lon2 DOUBLE)
RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE dist DOUBLE;
        SET dist = round(acos(cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lon1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lon2)) +  cos(radians(lat1)) * sin(radians(lon1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * sin(radians(lon2)) + sin(radians(lat1)) * sin(radians(lat2))) * 6378.8, 1);
    RETURN dist;
END$$
```

Comment: no @juergend's answer not working

Comment: Your code is working perfectly on `5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log`. What is your version? Are you sure you pasted the same code that you are using?

Comment: yes the code is exactly that what i am using my phpmyadmin on wamp. mysql version  5.5.24-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Maybe phpmyadmin is the problem, can you try directly with mysql cli? like save your query to `function.sql` and try to import it?

Comment: works fine on 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 and phpMyAdmin: 3.4.10.1deb1, too

Comment: Version information: 3.5.1, latest stable version: 4.1.12---my phpmyadmin version

Comment: i have also tried on hosting server but working giving the same err. version info is Server version: 5.0.96-community-log - MySQL Community Edition (GPL) ,Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13, phpmyadmin Version information: 3.5.1, latest stable version: 4.1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code in Mysql,and the same didn't work ;
but instead when I added an extra line it worked,
which was resetting the delimiter again
Kindly check

```
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And sorry in case if this also goes wrong..But worked fine for me